# Monte Carlo to solve sudoku puzzles

Tags: monte-carlo, sudoku

I am trying to figure out how to implement a Monte Carlo method for solving sudoku. I am looking at this blog post, however I can not figure out at all where he is pulling the number 243 out of

https://fromathenstoberlin.wordpress.com/2016/09/18/sudoku-solver-using-monte-carlo-simulations/.

Where 243 is the minimal energy of the system.

Answer (score 1):

I got it right as i posted the question.

9 unique elements in each row, * 9 rows = 81 
9 uniqe elements in each col, * 9 col = 81 
9 unique elements in each box * 9 boxes = 81

81 * 3 = 243